# Is it possible to extract mathematical expression of an trained ML Model?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning-model, mathematics

In Python & R, Linear Regression model gives the mathematical representation after learning the training data, typically in the form of intercept, coefficients of variables, and the p-value/t-value. Is it possible to extract mathematical representation of complex models based on Decision Tree, Random Forest, XGBoost, etc. after training it on a training dataset?

Answer (score 0):

A linear regression model is made of the parameters of a linear equation (intercept and coefficients), this is why the model offers a "mathematical representation". In other words, it's because the linear regression is based on a (simple) mathematical concept that it can be represented this way.

Other models are more complex and not only based on a mathematical representation. For example a decision tree model cannot be represented sa a mathematical expression, but obviously it can be represented by a tree.